# Define the FontFamily as a resource in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, resources, textbox, font-family

It's a little strange that after defining the FontFamily for the TextBox in the App.xaml, nothing changed. The code is

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Fonts/WenQuanYiMicroHei.ttf#WenQuanYiMicroHei"/>
    </Style>
```

When changing the TargetType into "TextBlock", the TextBlock will change its fontfamily.

Besides, I've also define a style for the TextBock like:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle4FF" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBox x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyContent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Is it because the Style definition for the TextBox?

So I decided to define a FontFamily Resource for the TextBox, but couldn't find a way to define the FontFamily. It seems that the FontFamily is in the `System.Windows.Media` namespace, but adding this namespace  `xmlns:media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=System.Windows"` is useless.

Any reply is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this pattern:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="CantarellFontFamily" >Fonts/Cantarell-Regular.ttf#Cantarell</FontFamily>
```

I created this one:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="CantarellFontFamily" >Fonts/Cantarell-Regular.ttf#Cantarell</FontFamily>
```

and I worked for me on Windows Phone 7.1 in the following way:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource CantarellFontFamily}" />
```

You can check the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily(v=vs.95).aspx

Regards,
Herber

Answer (score 0):

You have to base the new style on the already defined style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="baseStyle>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" 
            Value="Fonts/WenQuanYiMicroHei.ttf#WenQuanYiMicroHei"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle4FF" TargetType="TextBox" 
      BasedOn={StaticResource baseStyle}> <!-- based on defined style -->
```

As you can see you have to give the original style a key to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have to define those two styles (the style and the FontFamily) in two different XAML files, according to Theme Setting the user have chosen. So the baseStyle is invisible in the Style XAML file.